# Symfony2 + Doctrine, find in relations

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm thinking over to design an API to filter objects using fos_rest bundle in Symfony2 and Doctrine with MySQL.
Let's say I have a Master Entity, which has  relations with different entities which have some properties.
Now in frontend I would like to create a filter, where one can filter the Master Entity by the properties of the related Entities. How would that be doable?

say we have

```
+---------------+
| Master Entity |
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | Apple    |
+----+----------+
| 3  | Berry    |
+----+----------+
```

```
+-------------------+
| Property Entity   |
+----+------+-------+
| id | id_m | value |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  |  1   | green |
+----+------+-------+
| 2  |  1   | yello |
+----+------+-------+
| 3  |  1   | red   |
+----+------+-------+
| 4  |  3   | pink  |
+----+------+-------+
```

And I want to have a filter, where I filter by the values in Property Entity

I would like to do something like

```
$em->getRepository('AcmeBundle\MasterEntity')->findBy(array("PropertyEntity:value" => "red","PropertyEntity:value" => "yello"))
```

so it would return the object collection of Master Entity with ID=1 (apple) - because both parameters would match Apple

Answer (score 0):

You can create a query builder instead of use findBy

```
$qb->select('m')
   ->from('AcmeBundle\MasterEntity', 'm')
   ->join('m.PropertyEntity', 'p')
   ->where('p.value IN (:values)')
   ->setParameter('values',['red','yellow']);
```